# SQL Returning NULL when executed

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this SQL query return NULL when executed?

Please see the code - thanks in advance

Code:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, Client_AmntApplied)) AS AmountApplied
FROM 
    ClientDatabase C
WHERE 
    DateReceivedMonth = 1
    AND ADR1 = 2017
    AND StepStatus IS NULL;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the `Client_AmntApplied` column to int?  What type is this colunn and can you show us sample data?

Comment: check column value by `SUM(CONVERT(INT, isnull(Client_AmntApplied, 0)))`

Comment: well it is a varchar, and the problem shows when I added the "AND StepStatus IS NULL" in the where clause

Comment: StepSatus is of what type?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee It is a varchar and have a NULL value so I put the "AND StepStatus IS NULL" in the where clause

Comment: @YogeshSharma tried it but still the problem persist  :(

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because no sample data was given.

Comment: OH CRAPP, Sory for the expression. SO SILLY OF ME DAMN!! Clearly the problem is myself I have a mistake in the statement. sorry my bad It should be DateReceivedMonth = 11 NOT 1. aghhhhh!!!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there is no record to return with the where clauses.

```
WHERE DateReceivedMonth = 1
      AND ADR1 = 2017
      AND StepStatus IS NULL;
```

Check your where clauses and if you want to get `0` by default value just use `ISNULL`

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(Client_AmntApplied,0))) AS AmountApplied
FROM ClientDatabase C
WHERE DateReceivedMonth = 1
      AND ADR1 = 2017
      AND StepStatus IS NULL;
```

If there is no record to return and if you want to display a default value, you can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(Client_AmntApplied,0))),0) AS AmountApplied
FROM ClientDatabase C
WHERE DateReceivedMonth = 1
      AND ADR1 = 2017
      AND StepStatus IS NULL;
```

Comment: OP already tried `SUM(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(Client_AmntApplied,0)))`

Comment: @CallMeJeo, would you select the Client_AmntApplied field only ? Which records have been returning ?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee `SUM(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(Client_AmntApplied,0)))` will still return `NULL` when there is no record to sum.

Comment: so it means the problem is with the records right?
as OP said that it was working before this ` AND StepStatus IS NULL;`

SO I thought it might be issue with the null matching

Comment: @Rainman it is the Client_AmntApplied field as Amount Applied, for example my 2 records and their StepStatus field is NULL, so I need to put the StepStatus IS NULL in my where clause  in order to select those two records

Comment: My query is wrong without StepStatus IS NULL in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @ast varchar(10)

set @ast = null

SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, Client_AmntApplied)) AS AmountApplied
FROM ClientDatabase C
WHERE DateReceivedMonth = 1
AND ADR1 = 2017
and (StepStatus = ISNULL(@ast, StepStatus ) Or StepStatus is null)
```

in addition to this you can also replace the sum fucntion with `SUM(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(Client_AmntApplied,0)))`

Try this way

Answer (score 1):

Facts about SUM:

- Will return `NULL` when there are no records to summarize (WHERE conditions don't match any records or the table is empty)
- Will ignore `NULL` values in the summarized column (thus `COALESCE(column, 0)` is `ISNULL(column, 0)` has no effect on the result)
- Returns at least one record (which is NULL when there are no records to SUM)
- As a result of the first two, it will return `NULL` when all the values in the matching records of the summarized column are `NULL`

If you want to get 0 instead of `NULL` as the result when there are no records to summarize, you can use one of the following expressions:

```
COALESCE(SUM(column), 0) AS columnSum
-- or --
ISNULL(SUM(column), 0) AS columnSum
```

Or a `CASE..WHEN` construct (`COALESCE` is just a shorthand for this).

Check your queries results without aggregation to check if there are any records matching to your WHERE conditions.